# Each time I open my game error CS1001 error comes up

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine, fatal-error

Each time I try to open my game this happens

> Assets/enemy_health.cs(32,119): error CS1001: Unexpected symbol `)', expecting identifier

I cant find the answer.

PS its not only this but also other things like for these `;`

```
using System.Collections;
using UnityEngine;

public class enemy_health : MonoBehaviour 
{
    public float max_Health = 100f;
    public float cur_Health = 0f;
    public GameObject Healthbar;

    // Use this for initialization
    void Start () 
    {
        cur_Health = max_Health;
        InvokeRepeating("decreasehealth",1f,1f);
    }

    // Update is called once per frame
    void Update () {    
    }

    void decreasehealth()
    {
        cur_Health -= 2f;
        float calc_Health = cur_Health / max_Health;
        SetHealthBar (calc_Health);
    }
    public void SetHealthBar (float myHealth);

        //myHealth value0-1
        Healthbar.transform.localScale new Vector3 (myHealth.Healthbar.transfor.localScale.y.Healthbar.transform.localScale.z);
    }
}
```

Comment: I dont know what is wrong

Comment: Your SetHealthBar method is missing an opening brace { ...

Answer (score 1):

Your definition of `SetHealthBar` is malformed. It should be as follows. Compare it to the definitions of your other functions.

```
public void SetHealthBar (float myHealth)      <-- note the missing semicolon ';'
{                                              <-- and the opening bracket
    //myHealth value0-1
    Healthbar.transform.localScale = new Vector3 (myHealth.Healthbar.transfor.localScale.y.Healthbar.transform.localScale.z);
    // also don't forget to actually assign your variable, note the equals sign above
}
```

Comment: shouldn't there be an equals after `localScale` as well? Correct me if I'm wrong.